# using opencv2 write streaming video in python

Tags: python, opencv, video-streaming

In my project i want to save streaming video.

```
import cv2;
if __name__ == "__main__":
     camera =  cv2.VideoCapture(0);
     while True:
          f,img = camera.read();
          cv2.imshow("webcam",img);
          if (cv2.waitKey (5) != -1):
                break;
```

`
using above code it is possible to stream video from the web cam. How to write this streaming video to a file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply save the grabbed frames into images:

```
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
i = 0
while True:
   f,img = camera.read()
   cv2.imshow("webcam",img)
   if (cv2.waitKey(5) != -1):
       break
   cv2.imwrite('{0:05d}.jpg'.format(i),img)
   i += 1
```

or to a video like this:

```
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
video  = cv2.VideoWriter('video.avi', -1, 25, (640, 480));
while True:
   f,img = camera.read()
   video.write(img)
   cv2.imshow("webcam",img)
   if (cv2.waitKey(5) != -1):
       break
video.release()
```

When creating `VideoWriter` object, you need to provide several parameters that you can extract from the input stream. A tutorial can be found [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/highgui/video-write/video-write.html#videowritehighgui).

Comment: There is an AttributeError: 'cv2.VideoWriter' object has no attribute 'release'

Comment: @mridul you must import cv2 module first. with `import cv2`

Comment: and remember you can get the camera feed resolution width and height by camera.get(3) and camera.get(4), respectively.

Answer (score 2):

In ubuntu create video from given pictures using following code

```
os.system('ffmpeg -f image2 -r 8 -i %05d.bmp -vcodec mpeg4 -y movie3.mp4')
```

where name of picture is 00000.bmp,00001.bmp,00002.bmp etc..

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use the codec provided for your pc to compress the frames.

1. You should set the 2nd parameter of `cv2.VideoWriter([filename, fourcc, fps, frameSize[, isColor]])` with the flag value = `-1`. This will allow you to see a list of codec compress utilized in your pc.
2. In my case, the codec provided by Intel is named IYUV or I420. I don't know for another manufacturers. [fourcc webpage](http://www.fourcc.org/yuv.php).
3. Set this information as follow

   ```
   fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('I','Y','U','V')
   # or
   fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('I','4','2','0')
   # settting all the information
   out = cv2.VideoWriter('output1.avi',fourcc, 20, (640,480))
   ```
4. Remember two small parameters which gave me a big headache:

   - Don't forget the cv2.cv prefix
   - Introduce the correct frame Size

For everything else, you can use the code provided by Ekalic