# Save capture part of screen using mss to video using opencv2 in python

Tags: python, opencv

I want to save part of screen as video. When running code below I can see the window and fps count on it (around 100-140 fps).

Code (installed [mss](https://python-mss.readthedocs.io/installation.html) and [opencv2](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) are required):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
import mss

frame_width = 1280
frame_height = 720
frame_rate = 20.0
PATH_TO_MIDDLE = "output.avi"
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter(PATH_TO_MIDDLE, fourcc, frame_rate, 
                      (frame_width, frame_height))

with mss.mss() as sct:
    # Part of the screen to capture
    monitor = {"top": 120, "left": 280, "width": 1368, "height": 770}

    while "Screen capturing":
        last_time = time.time()

        # Get raw pixels from the screen, save it to a Numpy array
        img = np.array(sct.grab(monitor))
        img = cv2.resize(img, (1280, 720))
        frame = img

        cv2.putText(frame, "FPS: %f" % (1.0 / (time.time() - last_time)),
                    (10, 10),  cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        out.write(frame)
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

        # Press "q" to quit
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            break


# Clean up
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This code not produced any errors, so I don't understand what's wrong here. Output file `output.avi` created fine, but with size 5,7 KB (and this file I didn't open). I tried change `VideoWriter`, move `out` and `fourcc` inside the `while` - but didn't succeed. Also tried to change `frame_rate` and set frame `width` and `height` to more smaller values. Also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16045654/using-opencv2-write-streaming-video-in-python) question, but cannot succeed.

Comment: Can you please explain `while "Screen capturing":` ?

Comment: @balderman, it's from example [here](https://python-mss.readthedocs.io/examples.html#opencv-numpy). I don't fully understand if it needed here. After deleting it and remove `break` `mss` didn't capture anything and script finish from 0 sec from start. So, maybe this `while` are needed here. Such like `while` in `opencv`, maybe..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added those two lines  after `frame = img` helps:

```
frame = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

Maybe `opencv` can't save image as `np.array` so here need additional usage of `cv2.cvtColor`.

Comment: Legend. Very helpful, thank you. Great answer.

Thank you for adding the location in your answer.